# Pyinstaller on avc

Tags: python, pyinstaller

How can i use Pyinstaller on python scripts, that are using AVC(http://avc.inrim.it/html/)?

I have tried it in the normal way, and the output executable application throws error.:

```
ImportError: No module named avc.avcgtk
```

.

[EDIT]

I have installed pygtk and avc using pip.
Example scripts used from here, which runs fine on python:
http://avc.inrim.it/examples/gtk_spinbutton.py
http://avc.inrim.it/examples/gtk_spinbutton.glade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how this happens.

For normally running that example script using python, only  `from avc import *` is required
but for some reason pyinstaller does not finds avc.avcgtk module, so an additional dummy import is also required while creating standalone application with pyinstaller.

```
from avc import *
import avc.avcgtk
```